# Does CACHE TABLE persist if session is restarted?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a scenario where I'm reading data from remote storage:

```py
df = spark.read.load("abfss://mycontainer@mystorageacct.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata.csv")
```

It's a small dataset of a few GBs and it takes around 1 to 2 mins to load.

The same notebook is manually run everyday and I'm looking to make some small optimisations.

It appears `cache()` and `persist()` will not help because the data will be `uncached\unpersisted` at the end of the session?

Is it an ok pattern to write the data to local storage on the cluster and read it from there, e.g.

```py
localfile = '/X/myfile.parquet'

if os.path.exists(localfile):
   df = spark.read.parquet(localfile)
else:
   df = spark.read.csv("abfss://mycontainer@mystorageacct.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata.csv")
   # do some basic munging
   df.write.parquet(localfile)
```

How can I determine where the local disks (i.e. disks attached to driver and worker nodes) are mounted and are the users permitted to write to them?

---

Update:

The cluster will occasionally get restarted, but not often.

Comment: I'm referring to local storage as the disks attached to the cluster

Comment: but does the cluster runs all the time, or restarted periodically?

Comment: really, you always need to convert CSV into Delta, so you can get advantage of predicate pushdowns, data skipping, etc. In this case it shouldn't be much different if you use cloud storage

Comment: @AlexOtt - understand, thanks.  In this case the csv file is owned by another team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your cluster is restarted periodically, I would not write to disk but instead as a Delta Table to cloud storage (S3, Azure Blob Storage) if possible.

This should speed up your query immensely.